# In Salmon Run, if you die during the final wave after meeting the egg quota, does it count as a loss?

Tags: splatoon-2

When playing Salmon Run, each wave has a minimum egg quota that must be met in order to move on to the next wave. Failing to meet the quota results in a loss.

What happens if a team meets the egg quota in the final wave of Salmon Run, but each player dies before the timer runs out? Does it count as a victory or a loss?

Comment: Luckily, if the whole team dies at the end of the final wave it will still count as a victory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full team wipe counts as a loss, even if you meet the egg quota.

However, since you are in the final wave, there's no penalty in point reductions.

- If your team gets wiped out or fails to make your quota during wave 1, you lose 20 points from your Job Score (10% on the points modifier), and none of your previously collected points.
- If your team loses on the second round, you lose 10 points from your Job Score (5%).
- If your team loses in the third round, you don't have any penalty.

Comment: Neither would decrease. Pay Grade decrease by 20% if you lose 1st round, 10% 2nd round and not at all 3rd